# Can I rotate between stock and/or live wallpapers?

Tags: wallpaper, live-wallpaper

I like the Living Universe wallpapers that come with android. I want to rotate between several of them. I tried setting up the Wallpaper Changer app, but I see no way to add them to its list (or any other stock wallpaper, for that matter). Is there a similar app or setting that works for stock and/or live wallpapers?